# Unable to launch VS Code from terminal

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, iterm2, zshrc

Hello Im trying to launch VS Code from terminal using `code .` but getting errors:

```
/usr/local/bin/code: line 6: python: command not found
/usr/local/bin/code: line 10: ./MacOS/Electron: No such file or directory
```

This command used to work fine until maybe recently when I updated my OS.
Device: MBA 13" M1
OS: 12.3

Ive tried to install PATH from VS Code using `Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH`

Also tried adding: `export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"` to my `~/.zshrc` sourced it and restarted everything.

Answer (score 0):

I had python3 installed through brew so I simply ran

`ln -s /opt/homebrew/bin/python3 /opt/homebrew/bin/python`